# EClipse plugin: Draw Horizontal lines between methods in Java IDE

Tags: eclipse

I tried to search the eclipse plugins website but it was giving a server error on Searching, so anyway I was wondering if their a EClipse plugin that can draw horizontal lines between method in eclise, so when I close a method with "}" and hit ENTER, it draws a horizontal line under the method...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning in one of the more recent Eclipse builds there is a preference for "Method Boundary Lines" under `Window | Preferences | Java | Editor`

Comment: using Indigo and cannot find it. maybe I should also update Indigo?

Comment: Worth a try, but it may have been in one of the 3.8 nightly builds that I had installed.  From the sounds of [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13672), it may not be in the release builds yet.

Comment: I don't see the option in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno 20120614-1722)  :(